# ImageView is inflated but not displaying image

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview

I am using `PercentRelativeLayout` every thing is working fine but no matter what i do my `ImageView` is not displaying anything, i tried setting background as well as image from drawable folder,

Here is my layout

```
<android.support.percent.PercentRelativeLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/root"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/left"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:background="#6f7f9a"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        app:layout_heightPercent="45%"
        app:layout_widthPercent="62%">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/author_layout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="45dp"
                android:gravity="center">

                <com.mikhaellopez.circularimageview.CircularImageView
                    android:id="@+id/circleImageView"
                    android:layout_width="30dp"
                    android:layout_height="30dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/img_person_2"
                    app:civ_border_color="@color/white"
                    app:civ_border_width="1dp" />

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/p_name"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Akshay katariya"
                        android:textAllCaps="false"
                        android:textColor="@color/white"
                        android:textSize="12sp"
                        android:textStyle="normal" />
                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:text="The uprise"
                android:textColor="#fff" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView2"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_circle"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:text="sometext"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:textSize="12sp"
                    android:textStyle="normal" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_circle"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:text="sometext"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:textSize="12sp"
                    android:textStyle="normal" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_circle"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:text="sometext"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:textSize="12sp"
                    android:textStyle="normal" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView3"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_circle"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:text="sometext"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:textSize="12sp"
                    android:textStyle="normal" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_circle"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:text="sometext"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:textSize="12sp"
                    android:textStyle="normal" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="35dp"
                android:gravity="right|center"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:weightSum="1">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="left"
                    android:text="The uprise"
                    android:textColor="#fff" />

                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/btn_download"
                    android:layout_width="18dp"
                    android:layout_height="18dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="7dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="7dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/ic_download_dark" />

                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/btn_bm"
                    android:layout_width="18dp"
                    android:layout_height="18dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="7dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="7dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/ic_bookmark_dark" />

                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/btn_like"
                    android:layout_width="18dp"
                    android:layout_height="18dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="7dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/ic_heart_outline_dark" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/main_image"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/left"
        android:background="@color/colorAccent"
        android:src="@drawable/image_one"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        app:layout_heightPercent="45%" />

</android.support.percent.PercentRelativeLayout>
```

Here is my [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0y1dN.jpg) of how my layout looks:

[image: screenshot]

I have enabled layout bounds from developer options to see whether my image view is getting inflated or not, it seems its is inflated correctly.

This is what i am expecting:-

[image: screenshot]

If you want to debug just create project with `RecyclerView` and pass this layout in adapter.

Comment: I don't know why my last line of layout is not visible but i have closed my </android.support.percent.PercentRelativeLayout> properly

Comment: can you share a small project having the same layout, So that I can debug in my system

Comment: If possible share the expected output reference as well

Comment: @KrishanuDey just create new project and replace this layout with activity_main.xml that's shortest way around.

Comment: Please share the expected output, so that I can give you an workaround

Comment: I have added my expected output can you edit it so it will be visible for all of us

Comment: You should consider using ConstraintLayout as PercentageRelativeLayout is deprecated. However, I am trying to solve it. Will get back to you if i find solution. :-)

Answer (score 0):

This is what I could achieve
[image: This is what I could achieve]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/root"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="100">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/left"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:minHeight="250dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_weight="62"
        android:background="#6f7f9a"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/author_layout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="45dp"
                android:gravity="center">

                <com.mikhaellopez.circularimageview.CircularImageView
                    android:id="@+id/circleImageView"
                    android:layout_width="30dp"
                    android:layout_height="30dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_circle"
                    app:civ_border_color="@color/white"
                    app:civ_border_width="1dp" />

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/p_name"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Akshay katariya"
                        android:textAllCaps="false"
                        android:textColor="@color/white"
                        android:textSize="12sp"
                        android:textStyle="normal" />
                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:text="The uprise"
                android:textColor="#fff" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView2"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_circle"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:text="sometext"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:textSize="12sp"
                    android:textStyle="normal" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_circle"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:text="sometext"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:textSize="12sp"
                    android:textStyle="normal" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_circle"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:text="sometext"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:textSize="12sp"
                    android:textStyle="normal" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView3"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_circle"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:text="sometext"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:textSize="12sp"
                    android:textStyle="normal" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_circle"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:text="sometext"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:textSize="12sp"
                    android:textStyle="normal" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="35dp"
                android:gravity="right|center"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:weightSum="1">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="left"
                    android:text="The uprise"
                    android:textColor="#fff" />

                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/btn_download"
                    android:layout_width="18dp"
                    android:layout_height="18dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="7dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="7dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/ic_circle" />

                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/btn_bm"
                    android:layout_width="18dp"
                    android:layout_height="18dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="7dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="7dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/ic_circle" />

                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/btn_like"
                    android:layout_width="18dp"
                    android:layout_height="18dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="7dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/ic_circle" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/main_image"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/left"
        android:layout_weight="38"
        android:background="@color/colorAccent"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/image_one" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**Update**
Removed redundant `LinearLayout` & added `minHeight` to `@+id/left`